# Ionic: date pipe and local date

Tags: angularjs, date, ionic-framework

I want to print creation dates for news posts. I used the date pipe of angular.

```
{{news.created_at | date:'shortDate'}}
```

I saw after testing on my smartphone (language: german), that the dates are in english format (e.g. 10/26/2017).

Is there an option to format date in ionic according to the device language?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can apply date filter like this in your required format.This is helpful method if your app is mostly for some particular countries you can change date format for them and let other countries pick up the default case.

```
<p>Date = {{ today | date :  "dd.MM.y" }}</p>
```

Consider [This link for more info](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

All you need to do is:
Use

```
navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage
```

To get the device language 
Then based on language create a date variable to store the format for that language  like `$scope.dateFormat = "dd.MM.y"`

And then use it in your html like `| date : dateFormat`

Comment: Great idea! Thank you